Converting Calendar Dates to Fiscal Weeks in R
I have a data frame in R with a column (Date format) with entries like this : 2020-04-01
I can extract the week number (1 to 52) from each of these dates using the week() function in R (using the jan-dec calendar).
I want to do the same thing now, but for the fiscal week, i.e. the april-april calendar.
I tried a few options but there does not seem to be a quick way to do this. Does anyone know if there is a standard way to do this in R?

Here is a draft idea I was working on...
fiscal_week <- function(date) {
  date <- as.Date(date)
  
  fiscal_start <- ymd(paste(year(date) - ifelse(month(date) < 4, 1, 0), "04-01", sep = "-"))
  
  week_num <- as.integer((date - fiscal_start) / 7) + 1
  
  return(week_num)
}

df <- data.frame(Date = as.Date(c("2020-04-01", "2020-05-01", "2020-06-01")))
df$Fiscal_Week <- sapply(df$Date, fiscal_week)
print(df)


To be specific, is your first fiscal year week the one that contains April 1, or the first one that starts at or after April 1?

I think the key is to keep in mind lap years and using integer division.
A correct version of the function (considering lap years) is
library(lubridate)

fiscal_week <- function(date) {
  # Convert date to Date object if not already
  date <- as.Date(date)
  
  # Define fiscal year start based on whether the date is before or after April 1
  fiscal_start <- as.Date(paste0(year(date) - ifelse(month(date) < 4, 1, 0), "-04-01"))
  
  # Calculate the difference in days and convert to weeks
  week_num <- ceiling(as.numeric(difftime(date, fiscal_start, units = "days")) / 7)
  
  return(week_num)
}

# Testing
df <- data.frame(Date = as.Date(c("2020-04-01", "2020-05-01", "2020-06-01", "2021-03-31", "2021-04-01")))

df$Fiscal_Week <- sapply(df$Date, fiscal_week)

df

        Date Fiscal_Week
1 2020-04-01           0
2 2020-05-01           5
3 2020-06-01           9
4 2021-03-31          52
5 2021-04-01           0

